# fetch all Contact Phone Numbers in Array swift

Tags: swift, xcode

i fetched all contacts information exactly like below . At the moment i just fetched a Phone Number from contact . **the question is how i can fetch all of Phone Numbers of a contact in String array to use it?**

Store Data :

```
class ContactStruct : NSObject {
        let identifier : String
        let thumbnailImageData : UIImage?
        let givenName : String
        let familyName : String
        let phoneNumbers : String
        let emailAddresses : String

        init(identi:String,img:UIImage?,name:String,family:String,phone:String,email:String) {
            self.identifier = identi
            self.thumbnailImageData = img
            self.givenName = name
            self.familyName = family
            self.phoneNumbers = phone
            self.emailAddresses = email
        }
```

fetch method :

```
class func generateModelArray() -> [ContactStruct]{
     let contactStore = CNContactStore()

     var contactsData = [ContactStruct]()

     let key = [CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactImageDataKey,CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
     let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: key)
     try? contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stoppingPointer) in
         let givenName = contact.givenName
         let familyName = contact.familyName
         let emailAddress = contact.emailAddresses.first?.value ?? ""
         let phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? ""
         let identifier = contact.identifier
        var image : UIImage?
         if contact.thumbnailImageData != nil{
             image = UIImage(data: contact.thumbnailImageData!)!
         }
         contactsData.append(ContactStruct(identi: identifier, img: image, name: givenName, family: familyName, phone: phoneNumber, email: emailAddress as String))
     })
     return contactsData
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
func extractNumber(data: [ContactStruct]) ->[String] 
{
     var arrNumbers = [String]()
     for number in data
          {
              arrNumbers.append(number.phoneNumber)
          }
     return arrNumbers
}
```

and use like this:

```
let arrayNumbers = extractNumber(data: contactsData)
dump(arrayNumbers) //<- this line prints on console
```

Comment: how to use your way in existed method  ?

Comment: inside your func add var arrNumbers = [String](), and change this line contactsData.append for this arrNumbers.append(phoneNumber) and the return line for this, return arrNumbers, and finally this  -> [ContactStruct] for this -> [String]

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all your `phoneNumbers` and `emailAddresses` variables should be an array of String and not String since you can have multiple of those.

More over i would make them a Dictionary like so `[String:String]` - more on that later.

```
class ContactStruct: NSObject {
        let identifier: String
        let thumbnailImageData: UIImage?
        let givenName: String
        let familyName: String
        let phoneNumbers: [String:String] // <----- the new dictionaries
        let emailAddresses: [String:String] // <--

        init(identifier: String, img: UIImage?, name: String, family: String, phones: [String:String], emails: [String:String]) {
            self.identifier = identifier
            self.thumbnailImageData = img
            self.givenName = name
            self.familyName = family
            self.phoneNumbers = phones
            self.emailAddresses = emails
        }
```

Secondly, when it comes to fetching phone numbers and emails you need to loop through them because they arrive of Type `[CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>]` which is an Array of phoneNumbers encased in `CNLabledValue`, which means that they have a value (phone number) and label which in this instance is type of phone number (i.e home, mobile, fax, esc.. more on that [here - from Apple
Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnlabelphonenumberiphone))

This is also why I would use a Dictionary `[String:String]` so you can keep them in a key-value relationship where the key will be phone type and the value is the phone number.

`["mobile": "(494) 232 1134"]` for example.

If I were you I would build a simple function to iterate through them and return your Dictionary ready, for example:

```
    private func getPhoneNumbersFromContact(_ contact: CNContact) -> [String:String] {
             var numbers: [String:String] = [:]
             var i = 1
             for number in contact.phoneNumbers {
                 if number.label != nil {
                     numbers[number.label!] = number.value.stringValue
                 } else {
                     numbers["unknown #\(i)"] = number.value.stringValue
                     i += 1
                 }       
              }
           return numbers
        }
```

You can always add your own flavour and style to it.
I would leave the job of writing the `getEmailAddressesFromContact` function for you :)

So your final `generateModelArray` Class might look something like this -

```
class func generateModelArray() -> [ContactStruct]{
     let contactStore = CNContactStore()

     var contactsData = [ContactStruct]()

     let key = [CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactImageDataKey,CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
     let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: key)
     try? contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stoppingPointer) in
         let givenName = contact.givenName
         let familyName = contact.familyName
         let emailAddress = getEmailAddressesFromContact(contact) // <--- only changes
         let phoneNumber = getPhoneNumbersFromContact(contact) // <--- are here
         let identifier = contact.identifier
        var image : UIImage?
         if contact.thumbnailImageData != nil{
             image = UIImage(data: contact.thumbnailImageData!)!
         }
         contactsData.append(ContactStruct(identifier: identifier, img: image, name: givenName, family: familyName, phone: phoneNumber, email: emailAddress))
     })
     return contactsData
 }
```